# Set radius of rounded rectangle in PowerPoint document with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, powerpoint

I insert a rounded rectangle shape into my PowerPoint presentation using Apache POI 3.16:

```
XSLFAutoShape cardRect = slide.createAutoShape();
cardRect.setShapeType(ShapeType.ROUND_RECT);
cardRect.setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
```

How can I adjust the radius of the rounded corners of the rectangle?

Comment: No idea how to do it in Apache POI, but shapes (most if not all) have a collection of one or more Adjustments properties.  In the UI, the yellow dots you see as part of a shape represent its adjustment properties.  A rounded rectangle has only 1 so (in vba-speak) you'd change the shape's .Adjustments(1) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not implemented in `apache poi` until now. But we can using the underlaying objects starting with [org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.CTShape](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/presentationml/x2006/main/CTShape.java#CTShape).

For getting further informations we can simply creating a simple PPT having a rounded rectangle shape using `PowerPoint` and then simply unzip the `*.pptx` file and having a look at `/ppt/slides/slide1.xml`.

For the radius of rounded rectangles we find there:

```
<a:avLst>
 <a:gd name="adj" fmla="val 25000"/>
</a:avLst>
```

in the shape's XML.

That means: There is a [gd(Shape Guide)](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf#[3665%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C51%2C157%2C0]) having the name "adj" and a formula "val n" where n is between 0 (min) and 50000 (max).

So:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.CTShape;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGeomGuideList;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGeomGuide;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CreatePPTXRoundedRectangelShape {

 static void setRadius(XSLFAutoShape autoShape, int percent) {
  if (ShapeType.ROUND_RECT.equals(autoShape.getShapeType())) {
   XmlObject xmlObject = autoShape.getXmlObject();
   CTShape ctShape = (CTShape)xmlObject;
   CTGeomGuideList ctGeomGuideList = ctShape.getSpPr().getPrstGeom().getAvLst();
   CTGeomGuide ctGeomGuide = ctGeomGuideList.addNewGd();
   ctGeomGuide.setName("adj");
   ctGeomGuide.setFmla("val " + (50000*percent/100));
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  SlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

  Slide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

  int slideWidth = slideShow.getPageSize().width;

  XSLFAutoShape cardRect = ((XSLFSlide)slide).createAutoShape();
  cardRect.setShapeType(ShapeType.ROUND_RECT);
  cardRect.setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  cardRect.setAnchor(new Rectangle(100, 10, slideWidth-200, 90));
  //default radius

  cardRect = ((XSLFSlide)slide).createAutoShape();
  cardRect.setShapeType(ShapeType.ROUND_RECT);
  cardRect.setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  cardRect.setAnchor(new Rectangle(100, 110, slideWidth-200, 90));
  setRadius(cardRect, 0); //0 radius

  cardRect = ((XSLFSlide)slide).createAutoShape();
  cardRect.setShapeType(ShapeType.ROUND_RECT);
  cardRect.setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  cardRect.setAnchor(new Rectangle(100, 210, slideWidth-200, 90));
  setRadius(cardRect, 50); //50% radius

  cardRect = ((XSLFSlide)slide).createAutoShape();
  cardRect.setShapeType(ShapeType.ROUND_RECT);
  cardRect.setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  cardRect.setAnchor(new Rectangle(100, 310, slideWidth-200, 90));
  setRadius(cardRect, 100); //100% radius

  cardRect = ((XSLFSlide)slide).createAutoShape();
  cardRect.setShapeType(ShapeType.ROUND_RECT);
  cardRect.setLineColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
  cardRect.setAnchor(new Rectangle(100, 410, slideWidth-200, 90));
  setRadius(cardRect, 33); //33% radius

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreatePPTXRoundedRectangelShape.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'll try this at work on Monday and let you know how that went. Thanks!

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks so much for the high quality, complete example showing not only a solution, but an approach to work around Apache POI's occasional limitations.